# Testing the flutter web build

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I followed the official [flutter guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web) on how to release a web app.

Indeed, I get the `build\web` folder with the following content

```
icons
favicon
index
manifest
```

If I click on `index.html` an empty browser window opens, *while the index.html file itself is not empty* How do I run this website?

The hint: run `python -m http.server 8000` is not clear to me. How does it connect to my webpage?

--- I get the following error message in my browser ----

[image]

Console:

[image]

[image]

Comment: how have you build your web projet? can you share the command? If you have use `flutter build web` and have an empty index.html file, it must be an issue with your project. Maybe you can share the command output and also the flutter version you are using?

Comment: The index file is not empty, it is just displayed as an empty webpage. I clarified this in the answer now.

Comment: ok, can you try this. you go the build directory with the command `cd build/web` at the root of your project. Then you run the command `python -m http.server 8000` , then open your browser and access the url `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: Python executes this command leading to ```Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ..```, but http://localhost:8000/ still leads to an empty, white page.

Comment: If you open the console, do you have 404 error? If it's the case that mean that your are not running the your web server inside the `build/web` folder

Comment: I don't have an error in the console but apparently in the browser

Comment: I was speaking of the console panel inside the browser devtools

Comment: I added both console outputs. I hope, I chose the correct ones. Do you mind sharing the flutter doctor configuration that worked for you?  And the python command